# Are JS hash maps really hash maps?

Tags: javascript, performance, hash

I have tried reading about javascript hash maps a lot including on stackoverflow. Many people seem to suggest how to create and use hash maps as well.

My question is more fundamental, are javascript hash maps lookups really O(1). I was told by a co-worker once that Javascript does not have any hash map implementation so internally the engine will still iterate through the set for you and when it finds a match it will show it.

Now this may vary from engine to engine but am curious from a performance perspective if key value pairs are better over just iterating and matching.

Comment: Strictly speaking there's no defined implementation, but in practical terms for modern JavaScript runtime environments your co-worker was definitely wrong. Object property lookup is very highly-optimized.

Comment: It may be worth noting that javascript implementations are browser-based. It isn't unlikely that this would differ between browsers.

Comment: As an aside, object property lookup usually doesn't involve hash maps, it involves something *even faster* (if you're interested, read up on V8's hidden classes and similar concepts in other JIT compilers). Back to the question: Do you recall your coworker giving any more detail? Can you ask *them* instead of us? Both would greatly help this question, as it's currently either too trivial ("They are." being the answer) or too open-ended (explaining the various ways objects are implemented and their performance implications).

Comment: JS CAN iterate - ' for (prop in data) {  ..'  - OR access directly ' obj.obj.val ' 

There might be a case for caching selectors for performance ( var cachedobjofobj  = obj.obj.obj.obj; ) - for the application needs. Perhaps you and your colleague are at cross purposes down to different language sematics, so not an easy question to 'answer' sorry.